# Backend Data handling for Push Notification in IOS and Android

Tags: push-notification, backend, data-handling

I am currently working on developing the backend for our company's mobile app. As part of our app's functionality, we need to send notifications to users based on specific events within the app.

The challenge we are encountering is that if we handle all the notification data storage and processing in the backend, it seems to be a very resource-intensive process. Currently, we are querying the database every hour, checking dates and times, and calculating specific days and times from the date mentioned in order to send notifications. This process is proving to be quite heavy on our server.

I am seeking advice and guidance on more efficient ways to implement this notification system within our API

I want to emphasize that I am open to exploring alternative approaches and technologies to handle notifications more efficiently. Whether it involves using different push notification services or any other strategies that align with Node.js and MongoDB, I'm eager to find a solution that reduces server load while ensuring timely notifications.

If anyone has experience with similar implementations or can provide insights into best practices, including recommendations for alternative push notification services or technologies, I would greatly appreciate your assistance.